# Doubt in proof that retract of connected subsets of manifolds are manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I just saw a proof of this theorem :

> Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold and suppose that $f:M\rightarrow M$ is smooth with $f\circ f=f$. Then the image of $M$ will be a submanifold. That can be found in section $1.15$ here [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/dgbook.pdf).

Now I have 2 doubts about the proof :

1. He writes that for $x\in f(M)$ we have that $T_xf\circ T_x f= T_x f$. Now for this to be true wouldn't we need to say that there is an open set around $x$ such that all the elements in there are in $F(M)$? It seems that if we just have that one point that wouldn't work, since the derivative seems to be something local .

2. By linear algebra we have the rank-nulity theorem that gives us that $ rank (T_x f)+ \dim (\ker (T_x f))= \dim M$ . I understand the construction that he does and it based on the rank-nulity theorem.  So we know the rank of a function does not need to locally constant , then in the proof the author uses the fact that $rank T_xf + rank(Id-T_xf)=dim M$ to prove that $rank T_xf$ will be locally constant. How does this happen ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equation $T_x f \circ T_x f = T_x f$ is nothing other than the chain rule applied at the point $x$ using the equations $f \circ f = f$ and $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Yes I understand that , I just don't see why that would be true since to definde $Tf : [x,i,a] \rightarrow [f(x),j,D(\psi_j\circ f \circ \phi_i^{-1})(\phi_i(x))a]$ and $T_x f $ is just the restriction, we need to have open sets involved and we don't know if we have an open set $U$ such that $x\in U\subset A$, I don't think we need to , @LeeMosher.

Comment: Your doubts are unclear to me, but they seem to be rooted in basic definitions regarding manifolds, atlases, tangent spaces, smooth maps, and derivatives of smooth maps. In the book you linked, those topics are clearly a prerequisite: the first chapter treats them very swiftly. I suggest you look for a more basic book on differentiable manifolds in which those topics are developed more slowly and fully.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure that I understand your first question.

Regarding your second question. Think about $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$. The rank is locally constant downwards if $rank(df_p)=1$ then locally around $p$ the rank is $1$. At the origin $p=0$, it is not the case. There is no open neighborhood $U$ around $0$ with $rank(df_x)=0$ for all $x \in U$. This is an example that the rank is not locally constant.

To understand where your reasoning fails think about $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ where $v_1=v_2$ and $v_1,v_3$ are linearly independent. the matrix
$$A=[v_1,v_2,v_3]\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$$
is singular and $rank(A)=2$. Moreover if you change the first coordinate of $v_2$ by $\varepsilon$ small enough the matrix
$$A_\varepsilon =\begin{bmatrix}v_1, & v_2+\varepsilon\cdot e_1 &,v_3\end{bmatrix}$$
will be nonsingular. Hence $\det(A_\varepsilon)\ne 0$. Its true that the determinant is continuous but $\{0\}$ is a closed set hence a singular square submatrix in the Jacobian can turn non singular.

Comment: That is true , guess my argument doesn't work. Just can't see where it fails since it revolves around the continuity of the functions involved and the determinant.

Comment: I just edited my answer I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it helps, thank you .  But now I am confused about something. So we know the rank of a function does not need to locally constant , then in the proof the author uses the fact that $rank T_xf + rank(Id-T_xf)=dim M$ to prove that $rank T_xf$ will be locally constant. How does this happen ? @Elad